# Where to put js code for polling tile notifications for windows8 js&html app

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761476.aspx

Those instructions are great, but where do I *put* the below code (grabbed from article above)? In my `default.js` file, above the `app.addEventListener("activated", function (args) {` line of code?  Below that line?  Elsewhere?  Thanks Microsoft, but tell me where to put the code!

```
var notifications = Windows.UI.Notifications;
var recurrence = notifications.PeriodicUpdateRecurrence.hour;
var url = new Windows.Foundation.Uri("http://mytileprovider.com/tile.xml");

notifications.TileUpdateManager.createTileUpdaterForApplication().startPeriodicUpdate(url, recurrence);
```

Ideally this would just be a manifest setting with a dropdown of "Frequency" and an input box for the url to grab it from.  That would be oh so helpful and convenient.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is... it depends. :)

Where do you want to set up the tile and the polling?  Is it an "always on" feature that is core to your application?  If so, then put in inside the **activated** event for your default page (usually inside default.js).  Or maybe you are adding tiles based on content that the user interacts with (i.e., selecting a stock to pin to the Start page).  In that case, you would put that code inside the page that handles the user action that.

The simple answer is... inside the **activated** event.  The real answer, as you can see, can be more involved.

Comment: I put it inside `app.addEventListener("activated", function (args) {` in my default.js file, and the tile is not updating when I hit F5 in my Visual Studio. You can see the xml that I'm using here: http://www.godvine.com/api/live-tile.xml

Comment: IIRC, its been a while, a recurring update does not update the tile immediately.

Comment: it should update immediately and then at the occurrence interval with potential lag of 15 minutes. Are you using the Simulator?  You'd have to restart to see the change (that's a documented 'quirk' of the simulator).   As for where to register, activated is fine; for periodic it strictly only needs to really be done once for the lifetime of app: you're essentially just replacing it on each activation. That can be desirable, since the call to start the update does an immediate update then periodic after that.

Comment: I'm building this in Visual Studio, and in order to run it, I just hit F5, then I go to my Windows8 home screen (the tiles), hoping to see an update on my tile, but my tile just has the logo I've specified for it. Do I need to enable anything in the manifest for it to "listen" to tile updates? This should be easier :/